# Validation of an X509Certificate2 from a string Using fluent validation

Tags: c#, validation, fluent-nhibernate, saml, x509certificate2

I have this class

```
SAMLConfigurationValidator(): AbstractValidator<SAMLConfiguration>
{
  public SAMLConfigurationValidator()
  {
       //some rules....

      //My desired Code

      RuleFor(x => x.Certificate)
              .IsValid().WithMessage("Not a valid certificate");


  }

}
```

Essentially this needs to take a string (x.Certificate), create an instance of X509Certificate2 and than either use the .Verify() or .ChainPolicy methods to make sure that the string certificate that was entered by the user is a valid certificate.

I'm pretty new to Encryption and most cases or examples that I have searched for seem to be doing more of a use case verification.  Here I just want to check whether or not the certificate that the 'user' inputs is a valid certificate.

Solution:

```
public class ValidateCertificate 
  {
    public ValidateCertificate() { }


    static X509Certificate2 GenerateCertificate(string cert)
    {
      try
      {
        byte[] rawData = Convert.FromBase64String(cert);
        return new X509Certificate2(rawData);
      }
      catch 
      {
        return null;
      }

    }

    public bool Validate(string certificate)
    {
      var cert = GenerateCertificate(certificate);
      if (cert != null)
        return cert.Verify();
      return false;
    }
  }
```

You can than call

```
RuleFor(x => validateCertificate.Validate(x.Certificate))
        .Equal(true)
        .WithMessage("Not a valid Certificate.")
        .WithName("Certificate");
```

Answer (score 0):

I have answered this solution, and marked it in my original question.  Turns out that X509Certificate2 has a build in Verify that can be handy for validation.